golang gin when to use handleContext and when redirect
Having processed a GET request, I want to redirect the user to a new URL, handled by my app, which displays the results.
In the gin documentation I found two different ways to do this. One is to use gin's redirect() function and the other is to use it's router HandleContext() function. The cited documentation says redirect() should be used for a POST request or for a GET request but then says HandleContext() should be used for a "Router" redirect. I'm not sure I fully understand the implications of using one or the other.
The first use case given in the documentation cited above is:
r.GET("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, "http://www.google.com/")
})

What seems to be distinct here is that the redirecting is to an external URL, away from my app itself. The second use case, which is described as a 'Router redirect', is:
r.GET("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Request.URL.Path = "/test2"
    r.HandleContext(c)
})
r.GET("/test2", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{"hello": "world"})
})

So this seems to be required if the URL for the redirect is a path handled by my app.
But this is a URL like any other. So why not just use c.redirect() for Router redirects?
Intuitively, this is the obvious thing to do. But I suspect it produces unexpected behaviour (or at least, behaviour I personally didn't expect)
What's wrong with using c.redirect() for Router redirects, and what's the difference between it and router.HandleContext()?

The difference is that HandleContext() does an internal redirection that the client never notices, whereas Redirect() actually sends a response to the Http client notifying it, that the resource has changed.
I think this can be best illustrated by observing the DevTools of a Browser.
HandleContext():

As you can see, here the client never even noticed that the request was redirected to another handler internally.
Redirect():

Here the client was forced to make two requests to get the actual resource. Also notice that the URL bar now displays the URL of the redirected request.
Obviously making two requests leads to worse performance, which is why router.HandleContext() should be preferred for internal redirections.
If you want to test yourself, here is the code:
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    // Switch the uncommented block in order to see the effect of HandleContext.
    /* r.GET("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Request.URL.Path = "/test2"
        r.HandleContext(c)
    })
    r.GET("/test2", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{"hello": "world"})
    }) */

    r.GET("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, "/test2")
    })
    r.GET("/test2", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{"hello": "world"})
    })

    r.Run()
}


Many thanks. This clarifies. Just one question: am I right to think that there are no adverse consequences, over and above a slight decrease in performance, if redirect is used? I ask this because I'm also writing the server that handles API requests, and at least for development purposes, it's handy to test that the request has been sent.

If you are also fine with the client noticing the redirection, then the answer should be yes.

I discovered another difference between ctx.Redirect and HandleContext, which may interest others.
In some code I was writing, Redirect generated a warning, as follows:
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200

The code was as follows:
// if user has no simulations, redirect to the user dashboard
if user.CurrentSimulationID == 0 {
    ctx.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, "/user/dashboard")
    ctx.Abort()
}

which says that when users try to display a page with nothing useful in it, they get redirected to a page that lets them generate something useful.
If I understand right, Redirect creates a header with a 301 status. But the page I'm redirecting to wants to generate a header with a 200 status.
The following code does not produce this clash:
// if user has no simulations, redirect to the user dashboard
if u.CurrentSimulationID == 0 {
    ctx.Request.URL.Path = `/user/dashboard`
    Router.HandleContext(ctx)
    ctx.Abort()
}

There's probably a way to use Redirect in such a way that there is no warning, eg by a modified call to Abort. Or maybe a different call to Redirect, that doesn't set a status.
I had a look around but didn't find a solution that works. But in any case, the Router.HandleContext option seems better to me for the reasons given by @frankenapps.
The point of the above is that there seems to be a real practical difference between the two options, other than speed.
